# Audio Queue Converting sample rate iOS

Tags: ios

ok so, noob to iOS. I am using the Audio Queue Buffer to record audio. The Linear PCM format defaults to 44100 Hz, 1 channel, 16bit, little endian. Is there a way I can force a format of 8000 hz, 1 channel, 32bit floating point, little endian?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the format you want at initialization:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd;
asbd.mSampleRate = 8000;
asbd.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
asbd.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsFloat;
asbd.mBytesPerPacket = sizeof(float);
asbd.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
asbd.mBytesPerFrame = sizeof(float);
asbd.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
asbd.mBitsPerChannel = sizeof(float) * CHAR_BIT;
asbd.mReserved = 0;

OSStatus e = AudioQueueNewInput(&asbd, ...............
```

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try in the morning. what would I have to change to make it 16 bit?